# How to modify a dynamically created content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal

Firstly a bit of background: I'm modifying Drupal's backend (Node creation form) to dynamically add an html to a dynamically created element.

So, this is not a strictly Drupal question, as I believe what I want to know is within the realm of jQuery rather than Drupal.

In my form, I have a repeater (initially I have 1 textarea element, when I click on 'Add more' I'll have 2 textarea elements, and so on).

What I'd like to achieve is, trigger an event (hide elements, add others) when the 'Add more' button is clicked.

So I wrote this:

```
(function($) {
  'use strict';

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $container = $('#edit-field-updates tbody .draggable td div.form-item');
    $container.find('textarea').hide();
    var select = '<select><option value="template_1">Template One</option><option value="template_2">Template Two</option><option value="custom">Custom</option></select>';
    $container.append(select);
    $('html').click(function (event) {
        $container.find('textarea').hide();
        $container.append(select);
    });
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Note that the I achieve what I want on page load, which is to modify the element. The problem appears when the user click on 'Add more' to add more items.

PS: Ideally I'd like to post the original code that generates the repeater however I still haven't found it yet. This admin theme is based on the Rubik theme, but its a child theme developed internally by someone who's left so can't figure it out where it is.

I've also tried:

```
...
$('html').on('click', 'input', function (event) {
    alert('OI');
    $container.find('textarea').hide();
    $container.append(select);
});
...
```

Which does trigger the alert when I click on the page for the second time (I click on 'Add more', then click again anywhere on the page. I guess because I used 'html' rather than a element), however when I used a specific element rather than 'html' it didn't work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I've also tried:

$('#edit-field-updates-und-add-more').click(function() {
      $container.find('textarea').hide();
      $container.append(select);
    });

Which didn't work. Here's the html:

```
<div class="field-type-text-long field-name-field-updates field-widget-text-textarea form-wrapper" id="edit-field-updates"><div id="field-updates-add-more-wrapper"><div class="form-item"><table id="field-updates-values" class="field-multiple-table sticky-enabled">
     <thead><tr><th colspan="2" class="field-label"><label>Updates </label></th><th>Order</th> </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr class="draggable odd"><td class="field-multiple-drag"></td><td><div class="form-item form-type-textarea form-item-field-updates-und-0-value">
      <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable"><textarea class="text-full form-textarea" name="field_updates[und][0][value]" id="edit-field-updates-und-0-value" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea></div>
    </div>
    </td><td class="delta-order"><div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-field-updates-und-0--weight">
      <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-field-updates-und-0-weight">Weight for row 1 </label>
     <select class="field_updates-delta-order form-select" id="edit-field-updates-und-0-weight" name="field_updates[und][0][_weight]"><option value="0" selected="selected">0</option></select>
    </div>
    </td> </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="clearfix"><input class="field-add-more-submit button-add form-submit" type="submit" id="edit-field-updates-und-add-more" name="field_updates_add_more" value="Add another item"></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: can yopu please add your html too?

Answer (score 1):

Use...

```
$("#AddMoreButton").click(function() { 
    Your Code Here 
});
```

To add the click event only onto the button rather then the whole page. You can wrap that button .click() function with a document.ready() function so that the click event is set on the button when the page loads.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#AddMoreButton").click(function() { 
        Your Code Here 
    }); 
});
```

When you set...

```
$('html').on('click', 'input', function (event) {...
```

It causes the entire HTML doc to have the click event set on it.

Things to note: #AddMoreButton corresponds to the ID set on the button so it would look like this.

```
<button id="AddMoreButton">Add More</button>
```

Comment: I have tried that before and it didn't work. I've also tried `$("#AddMoreButton").on('click', function...` but that didn't work either

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle with Jquery import. https://jsfiddle.net/adio01/5b6jp3j9/ sorry im a JSFiddle noob, if it doesn't work import jquery on the LHS and hit run.